# jquery tabs not working using BBQ plugin

Tags: jquery

I have a question... and a problem.

I'm using Bens hashchange.js to make my links look like www.site.com/abc.php#123.php to tract history between tabs.

That works great, but then I also have a tab plug-in inside of 123.php which works great if you access the page via www.site.com/123.php, but if you try to access the page from the hashchange links then the tabs will become broken.

this is the tab code:

```
$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
$("#files_left_pane > ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
$("#files_right_pane > .tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content
//On Click Event
$("#files_left_pane > ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("#files_left_pane > ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
    $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
    $("#files_right_pane > .tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
    $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
    return false;
});
```

based off of that I don't see it checking the windows.hash for anything, so I'm not sure why the JS isn't being applied to the script.

This is the JS for my hashchange events:

```
var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;
$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();
$("#nav_profile_menu").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
    newHash = window.location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' );
    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#content-fill")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #content-fill", function() {
                    $pageWrap.animate({
                        height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                    });
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(900);
                });
            });
    };
});
$(window).trigger('hashchange');
```

By just skimming these codes and my scenario what could the problem be?

I'm thinking that the JS code isn't being applied to the new DOM elements being created via ajax by the hashchange.js plugin.

If thats the case, how can I trigger the JS to apply to the newly created content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `.live` or `.delegate` to add action listeners to items loaded in after the initial load of the page.

Check em out on [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: ya i'm aware of those functions, but i was more interested as to how i could use them with the existing script. I don't know where I would initiate it... or how